# Delete a set of lines from a file in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a Verilog file that looks like this:

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
module1
Line4
Line5
Line6
endmodule
Line7
Line8
module2
Line9
Line11
Line12
Line13
endmodule
Line15
Line16
```

Here I want to delete whole modules and the module names will be specified by me. Ex: I want to delete module1 so I want lines from module1 to endmodule to be deleted(module1, Line4, Line5, Line6, endmodule). And keep the other remaining modules intact.

My expected output when I delete module1:

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line7
Line8
module2
Line9
Line11
Line12
Line13
endmodule
Line15
Line16
```

How do I go about it?

Comment: Please show the code that you want help with, and describe exactly what problems you are having. If you have no code then your question is off topic for Stack Overflow: we will happily answer questions about *specific problems*, but if the problem is simply *"I don't know Perl"* then it is way too broad, and I suggest you start by exploring the excellent links in [the Perl tag information page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/info).

Comment: Will do. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use sed for this, not perl:

```
sed -e '/module1/,/endmodule/d' input.txt
```

`X,Y` specifies a range of lines to do something on, starting with the one matching X and ending with the one matching Y, and the `d` command basically says to delete the current line instead of printing it like normal.

If you're set on perl, the [scalar form of the range operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) (`..`) allows for the same sort of thing:

```
perl -ne 'print unless /module1/ .. /endmodule/' data.txt
```

Comment: Or `perl -pe '$_ x= not /module1/ .. /endmodule/'` if you want to be cute.

Comment: @melpomene Being cute is what gave perl a bad name.